# How to make sure that button has been clicked?

Tags: c#, microsoft-ui-automation

Is there a simple way to check if my OK button was pressed?  Most of the times it is working perfectly, but 1 in 100 it fails:

```
AutomationElement rl = SomeMethod();
if (rl.Current.Name == "OK" && rl.Current.ControlType == ControlType.Button)
{
    InvokePattern click = (InvokePattern)rl.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
    click.Invoke();
}
```

I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a notification after your button has been pressed you can register an AutomationEventHandler via

```
Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, AutomationElement yourAE,TreeScope.Element, new AutomationEventHandler(OnStartInvoke));

private static void OnStartInvoke(object src, AutomationEventArgs e)
{
    //logic
}
```

you could use this in order to verify that the button has been clicked also. Invoke the button in a scheduler (with a certain timeout) until you enter your OnStartInvoke.